# Reading multiple scripts from drive repeatedly in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am solving large systems of non-linear PDEs using neural network and I have a total of 10 classes as python scripts mounted on the drive in colab. My algorithm in the main python script calls these 10 classes back and forth to find the solution in an iterative fashion. Training takes a lot of time even with the GPU and I am wondering if this is because of the main script repeatedly calling the classes from the drive. The scripts are not large in size (max 1000 lines each) though and I am not importing any data (all data are simulated from within the main script).

Any thoughts on this are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just to see if it helps, could you try to copy them from your drive to the VM by doing `!cp <path to file in drive> /usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @rchurt Thanks for the tip. How do I refer to the /usr/local/bin to execute the file? Is it 'cd /usr/local/bin'? and then '!python file_name.py'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to copy the files to the VM and run them from there:

```
%%shell
cp <path to file in drive> /usr/local/bin
python /usr/local/bin/file_name.py
```

Comment: Thanks! It definitely works for the CPU. Will it also work for GPU? I am unable to test it since colab GPUs are unavailable for me since yesterday (strange!).

Comment: I just checked and GPU is still slower than CPU even after copying the files to bin as you suggested. I have no idea why :(

Comment: Did you write your code to run on a GPU? Usually you can’t just run code written to run on a CPU on a GPU and have it be faster—you have to modify it to take advantage of the parallelism of a GPU

Comment: I installed tensorflow gpu version and selected 'GPU' option in colab runtime. Isn't it sufficient? Thanks.

Comment: Probably not—I would ask this as a separate question and post the code you want to run on a GPU

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem, I resolved it by doing two simple things

1. As mentioned by rchurt, I copied the file to the path
2. Importantly, I created a single .py module (wrote classes instead of functions and embedded them in the same file) to avoid going back and forth from multiple files. This worked like a charm.